# Understanding ROUGE vs BLEU

Tags: python, nlp, text-processing, rouge, bleu

I am looking into metrics for measuring the quality of text-summarization.
For this, I have found this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38045290/text-summarization-evaluation-bleu-vs-rouge) which states:

> Bleu measures precision: how much the words (and/or n-grams) in the
> machine generated summaries appeared in the human reference summaries.
>
> Rouge measures recall: how much the words (and/or n-grams) in the
> human reference summaries appeared in the machine generated summaries.

Although in this [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/301626/interpreting-rouge-scores/312354#312354) of SE I find this:

> ROUGE-n recall=40% means that 40% of the n-grams in the reference
> summary are also present in the generated summary.
>
> ROUGE-n precision=40% means that 40% of the n-grams in the generated summary
> are also present in the reference summary.
>
> ROUGE-n F1-score=40% is
> more difficult to interpret, like any F1-score.

This is contradictory. Its sounds like **Rouge-Precision** is **equal** to **BLEU** and **Rouge-Recall** is **equal** to the statement made in the **SO answer**. Is Rouge-Precision the same as BLEU as it implemented BLEU?

It is also stated in the [paper](https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/W04-1013.pdf):

> It is clear that ROUGE-N is a recall-related measure because the
> denominator of the equation is the total sum of the number of n-grams
> occurring at the reference summary side. A closely related measure,
> BLEU, used in automatic evaluation of machine translation, is a
> precision-based measure.

I dont understand this, as (atleast) **rouge** returns a **precision** and a **recall** value. Can anybody bring some clearness into this?
Thank you!